# Thread not executing UI comes out saying unfortunately stopped

Tags: android, eclipse

Where timer is a textview and throws error during runtime and UI comes out saying unfortunately has stopped.Have  attached error mess link below.Plz help not understanding where I am going wrong

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.level_twolayout);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                            Timer.setText("Hello");
                        }
                    }
                });         
                t1.start();
        }
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

You must update UI from main thread.

Use this code. in place of Timer.setText("Hello");

```
// verify we are indeed updating UI on main thread.
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // go ahead and update UI
        Timer.setText("Hello");
    }
});
```

runOnUiThread is an Activity method. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29.

You need to call MyActivityName.this.runOnUiThread() or more simply just runOnUiThread() as "this" will point to the scope of the Runnable you are creating and not your Activity.

Lastly, "Timer" may not be the best name for your TextView.